# How to resize Webview height based on HTML content in Windows 10 UWP?

Tags: javascript, c#, webview, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am currently working on Windows 10 UWP App and facing an issue with WebView that when I have less HTML content, I am getting more height in javascript. My Code is as follows

```
WebView webView = new WebView() { IsHitTestVisible = true };
                string notifyJS = @"<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>

                                            function setupBrowser(){
                                            document.touchmove=function(){return false;};;
                                            document.onmousemove=function(){return false;};
                                            document.onselectstart=function(){return false;};
                                            document.ondragstart=function(){return false;}
                                            window.external.notify('ContentHeight:'+document.body.firstChild.offsetHeight);
                                            //window.external.notify('ContentHeight:'+document.getElementById('pageWrapper').offsetHeight);
                                            var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
                                            for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
                                               links[i].onclick = function() {
                                                    window.external.notify(this.href);
                                                        return false;
                                            }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </script>";


                string htmlContent;
                if (hexcolor != null)
                {
                    htmlContent = string.Format("<html><head>{0}</head>" +
                                                    "<body onLoad=\"setupBrowser()\" style=\"margin:0px;padding:0px;background-color:{2};\">" +
                                                    "<div id=\"pageWrapper\" style=\"width:100%;word-wrap:break-word;padding:0px 25px 0px 25px\">{1}</div></body></html>",
                                                    notifyJS,
                                                    formItem.I_DEFAULT_VALUE,
                                                    hexcolor);
                }
```

Here formItem.I_DEFAULT_VALUE is
`HTML without html,head and body tags` and its value is

```
<p>
<span style="font-size: 14px;">To help us investigate your query please can you make a sheet using the following&nbsp;</span><a href="http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf" style="font-size: 14px;" target="_blank">document</a><span style="font-size: 14px;">.</span></p>
<p>
<strong><span style="font-size: 14px;">Testing WebView Height</span></strong></p>
```

HexColor is background color that needs to be applied.

And my script_notify method is as follows:

```
webView.ScriptNotify += async (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.Value.StartsWith("ContentHeight"))
                    {
                        (sender as WebView).Height = Convert.ToDouble(e.Value.Split(':')[1]);
                        return;
                    }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value))
                    {
                        string href = e.Value.ToLower();
                        if (href.StartsWith("mailto:"))
                        {
                            LauncherOptions options = new LauncherOptions();
                            options.DisplayApplicationPicker = true;
                            options.TreatAsUntrusted = true;
                            var success = await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(e.Value), options);
                        }
                        else if (href.StartsWith("tel:"))
                        {
                            LauncherOptions options = new LauncherOptions();
                            options.DisplayApplicationPicker = true;
                            options.TreatAsUntrusted = true;
                            var success = await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(e.Value), options);
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            LauncherOptions options = new LauncherOptions();
                            options.DisplayApplicationPicker = true;
                            options.TreatAsUntrusted = true;
                            var success = await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(e.Value), options);
                        }
                    }
                };
```

Can someone suggest why I am getting very large height even if content is small?

Comment: I made a demo from your codes, but didn't reproduced your problem. The webView's height got resized correctly. Could you please post the codes of `formItem.I_DEFAULT_VALUE` or maybe share a basic demo that can reproduce this problem. And I'm using `WebView.NavigateToString` to render the html content.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT I have added `formItem.I_DEFAULT_VALUE` and I am also using `WebView.NavigateToString`. Also, I am creating `webview` dynamically using C# not XAML.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Also use `window.external.notify('ContentHeight:'+document.body.firstChild.offsetHeight);`

Comment: Still not reproduceable. you can try my demo here:[WebViewDynamicHeightSample](https://github.com/elvisxia/WebViewDynamicHeightSample).

Comment: :-( Don't know why it is not working at my side. I will try to create demo project and will check if I can reproduce the issue in that.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Please check your demo in Mobile Emulator. It will give you extra height.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Also, I am using Latest SDK.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem now on windows phone or emulator. I will consult through internal channel. I'll let you know, once I get response.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT OK Thanks.Also, in mobile emulator/phone, it displays small size text if the HTML contains <li>,<table>,<th> tags. Please also the ask the internal team to check that also. WebView is a very useful control for developers.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Hi, did you got any response for this?

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar Thank you for informing this issue to us, we have logged this issue internally and the related team is investigating it.

Comment: @FranklinChen-MSFT Thanks a lot. Actually, I want to update my app on Windows store so was confirming.

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar Understood, currently I'm not sure if there is any workaround, if you have to meet your deadline, a fixed height or something to avoid user's complain may be helpful.

Comment: @FranklinChen-MSFT Ok will try that for now

Comment: @FranklinChen-MSFT Can you please tell me whether this issue will be fixed in next SDK Update ? I noticed that it works fine in 10.0.10586 Emulator but when I use 10.0.14393 then it doesn't work. Same for a mobile device.

Comment: @FranklinChen-MSFT,@ElvisXia-MSFT Is this resolved in Windows 10.0.15063 Creators Update SDK?

Answer (score 5):

you could try to parse the string "document.body.scrollHeight.toString()" after your content loads in order to set a new height for your webview.
Here's an example with NavigationCompleted but you could use a custom event

```
public static class WebViewExtensions  
{
    public static void ResizeToContent(this WebView webView)
    {
        var heightString = webView.InvokeScript("eval", new[] {"document.body.scrollHeight.toString()" });
        int height;
        if (int.TryParse(heightString, out height))
        {
            webView.Height = height;
        }
    }
}

public Page()  
{
    MyWebView.NavigationCompleted += (sender, args) => sender.ResizeToContent();
    MyWebView.Navigate(new Uri("index.html"));
}
```

Comment: Did you tried this? I tried similar in past but didn't worked

Comment: Yes last year. But our needs may not be exactly the same. When you say it didn't work, was the value returned by document.body.scrollHeight also to big, or did the "eval" fail ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are getting a value that is too high, I faced a slightly different issue: the height of the document I got was too small (the height did seemingly not account for images). I have tried multiple events (`NavigationFinished`, `LoadCompleted`, ...) but in none of these events I was able to get an accurate height.

What finally worked for me was waiting for a short period until I send back the height of the document. Not exactly a great solution, I hope I will be able to simplify this at some point. Perhaps this also works for your issue.

I inject a script that waits for 100 miliseconds and then sends it back. Even if the image wasn't fully loaded yet, the content size was accurate for me.

```js
window.setTimeout(function () {
    var height = document.body.scrollHeight.toString();
    window.external.notify("ContentHeight:" + height);
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the key is to be sure the WebView widgets are visible.  If they are invisible due to Visibility or just not yet added to a visible container, then the document.body.scrollHeight won't be a viable way to get the height of the contents. I have a ProgressRing in a modal popup in order to prevent app usage prior to being ready, instead of tying that to visibility.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35729134)